# how to run countdown with dates to count days in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

i need to countdown dates not times

how to run countdown with dates to count days in iphone sdk

Comment: Given that a day is 24 hours, you should be able to calculate one from the other... Seriously though, you need to be more specific about what you want to do and what code you have now.

Comment: i have date like 15/03/10 and 30/08/10 i need to countdown the days between this dates and know the number of days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDate future = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2010-08-30 00:00:00 +0000"];
NSDate past = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2010-03-15 00:00:00 +0000"];

int days = [future timeIntervalSinceDate:past] / 86400;
```

Comment: What happens if daylight savings time comes into effect? There is a whole section on [Calendrical Calculations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html) in the NSDate documentation that shows you how to avoid hard coding date changes with numbers of seconds.